# Issues with string splicing in python when using range and negative steps

Tags: python

I am playing around with python string splicing and ran into a behavior of python that I do not understand. Lets say you have a string and its spliced in three different ways:

```
str = "stackoverflow"

splicedStr = str[2:6]
#this spliced string would equal 'ackove'

splicedStr = str[2:8:2]
#this spliced string would equal 'akv'

splicedStr = str[2:8:-2]
#this spliced string would equal ''
```

I understand the first two splicing. However for the last example, where you have a negative step count, why wouldn't it equal `'vka'`?

Comment: first index in `start(included)`, second is `end(not included)` and third is `step`. What you did was `start` from `2` go till `8` and add `-2`  after every `step`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slice you're looking for is:

```
>>> s[-7:1:-2]
'vka'
```

which is also:

```
>>> s[6:1:-2]
'vka'
```

Note that you always start at the first index provided and you go until you hit (or are bigger than) the second index provided.  The third index is the stride.

In your case, you start at 8 (which is already bigger than 2) so you end up with an empty string.

I think you expected, with a negative stride, that the first index would be the position from the right hand side of the string.  That isn't the case -- negative indices count from the left side of the string.

As usual, [the official language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) states it more formally (and correctly) than I can.

> The slice of s from i to j with step k is defined as the sequence of items with index x = i + n*k such that 0 <= n < (j-i)/k. In other words, the indices are i, i+k, i+2*k, i+3*k and so on, stopping when j is reached (but never including j). If i or j is greater than len(s), use len(s). If i or j are omitted or None, they become “end” values (which end depends on the sign of k). Note, k cannot be zero. If k is None, it is treated like 1.

Comment: That makes more sense, so when you have a negative stride, does it reverse the start and stop indexes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the items from back how can you access later item then before item.

do like this:

```
str = "stackoverflow"
splicedStr = str[8:2:-2]
```

What actually you are doing:-
    splicedStr = str[2:8:-2]

```
's', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'l', 'o', 'w'
           !                             !!      
           # strat here                  # upto here

       # but stepsize is -2 so how it can proceed to Offlimit
```